# I cannot create a project with the ASP.NET MVC template in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I want to create a project with the ASP.NET MVC template in VS 2022, but after doing exactly set up like everyone else, I got a blank project with no item in there:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUaf.png)

I uninstalled VS2022 and downloaded it again but it still didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are plenty of fully documented tutorials and examples. Perhaps a bit more Googling will get you there.

Comment: I did googling but none of these help me, and most of that is the missing template and that is not my case.

Comment: @TrườngNguyễn What do you see in the "Individual components" tab of the VS installer?

Comment: many checkbox ?

Comment: @TrườngNguyễn I posted the answer, if it helps you, you can mark it as the correct answer so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by issues with dotnet environment variables. To prove what I'm talking about, I need to reproduce your problem first, like this (this applies to all .net based projects):

[image]

Then the correct solution to this issue is:

You can modify the environment variables and find the path "This PC -> Right click 'Properties' -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables –> System variables –> double click path"-> Delete "C:\Program Files (x86) \dotnet" and make sure there is "C:\Program Files\dotnet".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Of course, it may also be because "C:\Program Files\dotnet" is not the correct path. This requires you to find the correct installation location of your dotnet and modify it.

Finally, when your dotnet environment variables are configured correctly, you will find that everything is normal when you re-create a console program.